# Can you use private ip address in AWS policies?

Tags: amazon-web-services

For example, I want to restrict access to aws resources except when a user is in a specific VPC. I can create a role with the permission to those resources and set a trust policy for that user to be able to assume that role when they're on the VPC's public ip. Does iam policies work with VPC's without a internet gateway (ie can I do something similar with the VPC's private ip)?

I did some testing and it only seems to support public ips. Is there an alternative?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html : you can restrict based on the VPC, the VPC endpoint (which would be required in private vpcs) and the aws:VpcSourceIp

Comment: I think for IAM / STS you would need to create a STS VPC endpoint : https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_sts_vpce.html - that endpoint can then be used in the policy.

Comment: Thank you, Ill check it out. I think this solves my problem!

Comment: Note: when testing for the [aws:SourceVpc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-sourcevpc) condition key: you have to use a VPC Endpoint when making the request.

Comment: That makes sense because I have to use VPC Endpoint to request AWS resources in a VPC without an internet gateway, otherwise I can simply use aws:SourceIp with the internet gateway's ip.